# Why I am getting error in this code?? And the error is: expected primary-expression before ‘long’

Tags: c++, object, type-conversion

I am getting error in this code while converting the member data of the class `Int` to `long double` in the conversion operators. But I don't understand why this happens?

```
 #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

 class Int
 {
    private:
         int number;
    public:
        Int() : number(0)                                         // no argument constructor
     {     }

     Int( int i) : number(i)                                 // 1-argument constructor
       {     }

    void putInt()                                           // display Int
     { cout << number; }

     void getInt()                                           // take value from the user
     { cin >> number; }

     operator int()                                           // conversion operator ( Int to int)
     { return number; }

     Int operator + ( Int a)
     { return checkit( long double (number) + long double (a))  ; }  // performs addition of two objects of type Int
    
     Int operator - ( Int a)
     { return checkit(long double (number) - long double (a) ); }  //performs subtraction of two objects of type Int

     Int operator * (Int a)  
     { return checkit( long double (number) * long double (a) ); }  // performs multiplication of two objects of type Int

     Int operator / (Int a)
     { return checkit( long double (number) / long double (a) ); } // performs division of two objects of type Int

     Int checkit( long double answer)
     {
        if( answer > 2147483647.0L || answer < - 2147483647.0L)
          { cout << "\nOverflow Error\n";
             exit(1);
          }

        return Int ( int(answer));
     }
   
 }; 

 int main()
  {
    Int numb1 = 20;
    Int numb2 = 7;
    Int result, cNumber;

    result = numb1 + numb2;
   cout << "\nresult = "; result.putInt();                         //27
  result = numb1 - numb2;
  cout << "\nresult = "; result.putInt();                         //13
   result = numb1 * numb2;
  cout << "\nresult = "; result.putInt();                        // 140
   result = numb1 / numb2;
  cout << "\nresult = "; result.putInt();                        // 2

  cNumber = 2147483647;
   result = numb1 + cNumber;     // overflow error
   cout << "\nresult = "; result.putInt();
   cNumber = -2147483647;
  result = numb1 + cNumber;                                      // overflow error

  cout << endl;
   return 0;

  }
```

In the operator overloading code for the `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operators, I am getting errors of:

> expected primary expression before 'long'

I don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 6):

The nature of C++ syntax does not allow type names that consist of more than one word (like `long double` and `unsigned int`) to be used in functional casts, as you are attempting to do in the `long double (number)` and `long double (a)` expressions. (Just using a plain `double` type would be OK, though.)

But you really shouldn't be using such casts in a C++ program – they're almost as evil as C-style casts.

Whenever possible, [use explicit C++ casts, starting from the 'softest' available option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332030/10871073); in your case, `static_cast` will work for the `int` to `long double` conversion as well as any other; so, just change your binary operator functions to forms like the following:

```cpp
    Int operator + (Int a)
    {
        return checkit(static_cast<long double>(number) + static_cast<long double>(a));
    }  // performs addition of two objects of type Int
```